# PHP-app deployment tool from GitHub or Eclipse / EGit (FTP?)

Tags: eclipse, git, deployment, github, ftp

Historically I was using Dreamweaver to edit my PHP-app, at which time I was using the built in FTP-function to upload to the webhost. It was super easy. With the push of a button  (Ctrl + U) I could easily upload the file I had been editing to the correct folder at the webhost (after making some initial easy settings in Dreamweaver).

But now I am trying to get into the version control system mentality instead and I have started using EGit in Eclipse and I have successfully synced my project to GitHub and pushed my commits. I guess I use GitHub mostly for backup since I am the only one editing my app.

Now, as I mentioned before, deployment of my files was so **easy** in Dreamweaver, and **easy to manage**, I had total control of which files I was updating and total visibility. But now, deploying my project from Eclipse or GitHub doesn't look as easy. I have been trying DeployHQ.com to deploy my latest commits to GitHub, but found that to be a little unmanageable and not so easy (maybe I didn't try hard enough), then I tried Remote System Explorer in Eclipse, also not so easy and manageable.

I am looking for a tool or method to deploy my PHP app to my webhost file system from either Eclipse or GitHub that has been purposely built to be **easy easy and easy** and **intuitive**. Does such a tool exist? I am almost thinking about reverting back to my old Dreamweaver FTP-client just because I can't be bothered getting something like DeployHQ to work.

I guess it goes without saying that I am only coding part-time, so please be nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[FTPloy](https://ftploy.com/) offers a similar service that I used to use back when I coded PHP. It was easy to setup and integrates directly with GitHub or BitBucket.

Comment: In the end I went back to try DeployHQ. And I got it to work, so now every commit I make to GitHub for my project will be reflected live as well. Actually, the tool DeployHQ is easy to use, I tried FTPloy but I prefer DeployHQ. It was just me who was a bit retarded at the time when I couldn't use it, I had a problem when choosing which commits to deploy.  So I can recommend DeployHQ. But I have to say, none of these comes close to the easy of deploying with FTP in Dreamweaver. But then you don't have version control. Typical trade-off I suppose.

Comment: Just as another option, there's also [dploy.io](http://dploy.io) which is similar to DeployHQ, but more powerful and arguably has nicer UI.

Disclaimer: work on dploy.io